# Total of group_by summarize values

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data and a plot like the example I give below.

I'd like to have a third "Condition" that is the Total Sum of Amount for Condition A and Condition B for a given Year and Month. I don't know how to do that since Condition is included in the `group_by` statement. In particular, I'd like to be able to plot it on the same plot as what appears below (so there'd be a third line for each Year showing the Total).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(Amount = sample(1:100, replace=T), 
               Condition = sample(c("A","B"), 100, replace=T),
               Year = sample(2015:2017, 100, replace=T),
               Month = sample(1:12, 100, replace=T))
dataGrouped <- data %>%
               group_by(Year, Month, Condition) %>%
               summarize(sumAmount = sum(Amount))
ggplot(dataGrouped, aes(x=Month, y=sumAmount, color=factor(Year), linetype=Condition)) + 
    geom_line(size=1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

[image]

I've considered first doing a `group_by(Year, Month)`, then adding a Total, but still not sure what way would be best to do this (or if there's a better alternative).

Comment: Isn't your plot a little too cluttered as is? Is it essentially to keep the month and year separated or is it okay to plot in a continuous timeline (i.e. from Jan 2015 to Dec 2017)?

Comment: In this example data it is a bit cluttered. In my actual data, Condition A and B don't overlap like this. At any rate, it is preferable to have them on the same plot for ease in comparing values between Years for a given Month and Condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that summarizes the total by Year and Month and then binds it to the grouped data with a Condition value of "Total", so that `ggplot()` will pick it up as a new line in your plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(Amount = sample(1:100, replace=T), 
                   Condition = sample(c("A","B"), 100, replace=T),
                   Year = sample(2015:2017, 100, replace=T),
                   Month = sample(1:12, 100, replace=T))

dataGrouped <- data %>%
  group_by(Year, Month, Condition) %>%
  summarize(sumAmount = sum(Amount))

ggplot(dataGrouped, aes(x=Month, y=sumAmount, color=factor(Year), linetype=Condition)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)

dataWithTotal <- data %>%
  group_by( Year, Month ) %>%
  summarize( sumAmount = sum(Amount) ) %>%
  mutate( Condition = 'Total' ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rbind( ungroup(dataGrouped) ) %>%
  mutate( Condition = as.factor(Condition) )

ggplot(dataWithTotal, aes(x=Month, y=sumAmount, color=factor(Year), linetype=Condition)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

Comment: Both this answer and @Adam Quek 's worked with my data and were helpful. I've chosen this answer as it is more intuitive to me and works without me having to remove other columns in my dataset for melting.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2` melt and dcast to reform the wide format for data manipulation (to form condition C):

```
library(reshape2)
data <- data %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(Condition, Year, Month), .funs= funs(as.factor))
dat <- melt(data) %>% 
       dcast(., Year + Month ~ Condition, sum)
dat <- dat %>% 
       mutate(C = A + B) %>% 
       mutate(Month = as.numeric(as.character(Month)))
```

Form long format with gather:

```
dat <- dat %>% 
       gather(Condition, Amount, A:C)
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Month, Amount,color=factor(Year), linetype=Condition)) + 
      geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

[image]